# How to debug Laravel API request from ReactJs (Another Project) client?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

I have two projects one is developed by reactjs another one is by laravel. I want to get some data from the laravel project therefore, I access a method that is inside the laravel project controller folder via api call. if I hit the method from reactjs project, how to debug laravel project?

Comment: you could set up xdebug to allow debugging on the laravel side. https://javorszky.co.uk/2018/05/03/getting-xdebug-working-on-php-7-2-and-homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

the best tool is [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope)

and Take a look [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)